# SQL filter based on explicit 3 conditions

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, multiple-conditions

I have following query, which only select feature id of. 4,5 and 7:

```sql
SELECT
    p.id_product,
    fvl.value,
    fvp.position,
    fv.id_feature

FROM
    ps_feature_product                   fp
    INNER JOIN ps_product                p   ON p.id_product = fp.id_product
    INNER JOIN ps_feature_value          fv  ON fp.id_feature_value = fv.id_feature_value
    INNER JOIN ps_feature_value_position fvp ON fv.id_feature_value = fvp.id_feature_value
    INNER JOIN ps_feature_value_lang     fvl ON fv.id_feature_value = fvl.id_feature_value

WHERE
    fvl.id_lang = 1
    AND
    fp.id_feature IN ( 4,5,7 )
```

Three conditions needs to be added, based on each feature. Something like...

```sql
WHERE
    fp.id_feature = 4
    AND
    fp.feature_value_position >= 50 

    -- and so on (position can be grater or lower).
```

I have tried following:

```sql
SELECT
    p.id_product,
    fvl.value,
    fvp.position,
    fv.id_feature

FROM
    ps_feature_product                   fp
    INNER JOIN ps_product                p   ON p.id_product = fp.id_product
    INNER JOIN ps_feature_value          fv  ON fp.id_feature_value = fv.id_feature_value
    INNER JOIN ps_feature_value_position fvp ON fv.id_feature_value = fvp.id_feature_value
    INNER JOIN ps_feature_value_lang     fvl ON fv.id_feature_value = fvl.id_feature_value

WHERE
    fvl.id_lang = 1
    AND
    (
        (fv.id_feature = 4 AND fvp.position >= 100)
        AND
        (fv.id_feature = 5 AND fvp.position >= 20)
        AND
        (fv.id_feature = 7 AND fvp.position >= 20)
    )
```

But I guess, this will not work in theory. What is the best way to achieve this?

It's worth mention that all if the three criteria should be met. Like, of there is no products found with `id_feature = 5 AND fvp.position >= 80`, it shouldn't result any - even though e.g. `if fv.id_feature = 7 AND fvp.position >= 20` contains products.

I have also tried with OR instead of AND like so:

```
WHERE
    fvl.id_lang = 1
    AND
    (
        (fv.id_feature = 4 AND fvp.position >= 100)
        OR
        (fv.id_feature = 5 AND fvp.position >= 20)
        OR
        (fv.id_feature = 7 AND fvp.position >= 20)
    )
```

But this will output results, if just one of these three conditions is met. It should be based on all of them.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I think you need a `CASE fb.id_feature WHEN ...` expression.

Comment: You should use `OR` instead of `AND` (the 2 last ones), a feature can't be number 4, 5 and 7 at the same time. But as @Dai suggested, a `CASE WHEN` is even better.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? If you're using Oracle then you can use tuples in `IN` expressions, which simplifies things, but other RDBMS don't support this.

Comment: _"But this will output results, if just one of these three conditions is met. It should be based on all of them."_ - **that's impossible**: you have mutually-exclusive conditions on `fv.id_feature`. Do you mean to say you want to filter `ps_feature_product` if each `id_product` has _all three_ `ps_feature_value` values for `4,5,7`? If so, that's _relational division_ and is kinda non-trivial in SQL.

Comment: Your `ps_feature_value` table looks like an EAV table - that's an anti-pattern. Why are you using the EAV anti-pattern in your database?

Answer (score 0):

Using only `AND` and `OR`, but retaining the `IN` operator to make it easier for the query engine to keep the query SARGable:

```
WHERE
    fvl.id_lang = 1
    AND
    fv.id_feature IN ( 4, 5, 7 )
    AND
    (
        ( fv.id_feature = 4 AND fvp.position >= 100 )
        OR
        ( fv.id_feature = 5 AND fvp.position >=  20 )
        OR
        ( fv.id_feature = 7 AND fvp.position >=  20 )
    )
```

Though a `CASE <expr> WHEN <const-value>` expression works too, though you'll need to repeat the `fvp.position >= x` in a nested `CASE WHEN`:

```
WHERE
    fvl.id_lang = 1
    AND

    CASE fv.id_feature
        WHEN 4 THEN ( CASE WHEN fvp.position >= 100 THEN 1 END )
        WHEN 5 THEN ( CASE WHEN fvp.position >=  20 THEN 1 END )
        WHEN 7 THEN ( CASE WHEN fvp.position >=  20 THEN 1 END )
    END
```

or as `CASE WHEN <expr> THEN`:

```
WHERE
    fvl.id_lang = 1
    AND

    CASE 
        WHEN fv.id_feature = 4 AND fvp.position >= 100 THEN 1 END )
        WHEN fv.id_feature = 5 AND fvp.position >=  20 THEN 1 END )
        WHEN fv.id_feature = 7 AND fvp.position >=  20 THEN 1 END )
    END
```

As always, check your query-plan to ensure it's still using your indexes appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question-edits, I gather your `ps_feature_value` table is an EAV anti-pattern table (ew). One approach is to design the query to undo the *crappy, awful, Codd's-grave-desecrating* EAV design by promoting those row-values back into columns, [*the way Codd intended*](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ezives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf).

*Moving on*... this query should give you the results you want:

```
WITH products_with_features_4_5_7 AS (

    SELECT
        fp.id_product,

        MIN( CASE fp.id_feature WHEN 4 THEN fp.id_feature_value END ) AS feature4,
        MIN( CASE fp.id_feature WHEN 5 THEN fp.id_feature_value END ) AS feature5,
        MIN( CASE fp.id_feature WHEN 7 THEN fp.id_feature_value END ) AS feature7,

        MIN( CASE fp.id_feature WHEN 4 THEN fvp.position END ) AS feature4pos,
        MIN( CASE fp.id_feature WHEN 5 THEN fvp.position END ) AS feature5pos,
        MIN( CASE fp.id_feature WHEN 7 THEN fvp.position END ) AS feature7pos

    FROM
        ps_feature_product                   fp
        INNER JOIN ps_product                p   ON p.id_product = fp.id_product
        INNER JOIN ps_feature_value          fv  ON fp.id_feature_value = fv.id_feature_value
        INNER JOIN ps_feature_value_position fvp ON fv.id_feature_value = fvp.id_feature_value
    
    WHERE
        fvl.id_lang = 1

    GROUP BY
        fp.id_product
),
productsSubset AS (

    SELECT
        id_product
    FROM
        productFeatures_4_5_7
    WHERE
        feature4pos >= 100
        AND
        feature5pos >=  20
        AND
        feature7pos >=  20
)
SELECT
    p.id_product,
    fvl.value,
    fvp.position,
    fv.id_feature

FROM
    ps_feature_product                   fp
    INNER JOIN ps_product                p   ON p.id_product = fp.id_product
    INNER JOIN ps_feature_value          fv  ON fp.id_feature_value = fv.id_feature_value
    INNER JOIN ps_feature_value_position fvp ON fv.id_feature_value = fvp.id_feature_value
    INNER JOIN ps_feature_value_lang     fvl ON fv.id_feature_value = fvl.id_feature_value

    INNER JOIN productsSubset ps ON p.id_product = ps.id_product

ORDER BY
    p.id_product;
```